# Attribute not showing category

Tags: magento2.2, custom-attributes, category-view

I am using Magento 2.2 for my store. I have created a custom attribute. I have modified list.phtml and catalog_product_view.xml and I have created a myatrribute.phtml. I have also enabled visible in storefront to yes for the attribute.

I have done re-indexing and flushed the cache.

My attribute is showing in product view and category view. The attribute is not showing in the Homepage category list.

Any idea how I can enable the attribute in homepage category list.

My custom attribute phtml file:

```
<?php
echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getMunit(), 'munit');
?>
```

Comment: which template do you use for Homepage category list ?

Comment: Im using Bizkick from Hiddentechies

Comment: Not theme but path to phtml file

Comment: app/design/frontend/Hiddentechies/bizkick_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

Comment: Can you add source to question?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: how did you render a category list in homepage?

Comment: How you connect your attribute phtml  to homepage category list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable **Used in Product Listing** to Yes and check.

Comment: I have added this but still not working

Comment: Can you tell me how you are rendering listing in homepage?

Comment: My homepage contains block which has catalog product listings + Product grid template

Comment: are you using widget for that? have you checked either your custom attribute is present in collection data or not?

Comment: Yes I'm using Widget. Please elaborate how I can check custom attribute in collection data?

Comment: As you are using widget i think it is using this template `Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`. so you can print item data like this in loop. `<?php echo "<pre />"; print_r($_item->getData()); die('die'); ?>`. if you can see your attribute in collection data then you can try below code to display attribute value: `<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getMunit(), 'munit'); ?>`

Comment: @Fast Source, Welcome :)